# Is this ram compatible with my motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

> Corsair Vengeance Pro DDR3 2400MHz 16GB 2x8GB CL11 XMP 1,65V
>
> ASUS Sabertooth Z77 socket  ATX,Z77, DDR3

I am currently using:

> Corsair Vengeance DDR3 1600MHz 8GB CL8
> Kit w/2x 4GB XMS3 modules, CL8-8-8-24, 1.5V

Btw, also what does the CL11 ( 11-13-13-31 ) vs C8-8-8-24 mean? How much should i care when selecting the ram to buy ? (Sooooo many options and I basically just know I want 16gig and fast.

That increase of 800Mhz for 0.15V .. How much will that volt really have of an impact?

Lastly, do you have a better suggestion? I want up to 16 gig and I want to get something good. Saving a few bucks is not a factor. Or a general explanation on how to select ram, what do you look for? Just too much options and they are so similar but with a few acronyms..

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you buy needlessly expensive memory? Your MoBo also falls in this category...

Comment: That is not very helpful... I love this motherboard. So clean and easy to build. I want faster ram than I have.

Comment: Then you have to replace it completely. Also, it won’t make your PC faster. It’s simply a waste, sorry. The increased amount will help, though.

Comment: Why must I replace? You mean the motherboard? Or replace my existing ram? Because that was the plan.

Comment: The existing RAM modules. Otherwise, you wouldn’t be able to use any speed improvements at all, because the “lowest performing” memory module sets the speed for all modules. Also, why not get RAM with standard form factors instead of useless heatspreaders?

Comment: Yes I plan on replacing the existing ones. I guess I assume the heatstpreaders arent actually useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MoBo will only support up to 1866mhz ram, so buying 2400mhz ram would only run at 1866 even if turned all the way up in bios. So I would just look for a good deal on 2x8GB of 1866mhz non ecc (desktop) ram. ex:
[http://www.amazon.com/Corsair-Vengeance-Series-Desktop-CMY16GX3M2A1866C9/dp/B00D2LGRO2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1408993418&sr=8-1&keywords=1866+16gb+ram](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D2LGRO2)

Also the lower the timing the better I believe, but I wouldn't worry too much about this.

IMO 16GB is rarely neccesary, maybe see how much your even using as most only use about 4GB. BUT, It's your money and if you want 16GB then by all means you buy 16GB =)

Comment: Thanks. 1866 max is very helpful. I am going for > Corsair Vengeance Pro DDR3 1866MHz 16GB 2x8GB CL9 XMP 1,5V, Silver  then i think

Comment: Also encase you didn't know, I would check the speed in bios after you install. Most MoBo's tha I've built are set to only run at 1600mhz, unless you overclock it to 1866mhz.

Comment: @alkemann That’s the XMP option, by the way. No need to do this by hand, just flip it on and you’re done.